# Wordpress get tags in “publish_post” hook

Tags: posts, tags, publish

I want to get the selected tags using `publish_post` hook, while publishing the post.

With below code, I can get only those tags which are already saved in the post. this will not work for new tags.

```
add_action( 'publish_post', 'post_published_notification', 10, 2 );
function post_published_notification( $ID, $post ) 
{
    $post_tags = get_the_tags($ID);
    if ( $post_tags ) 
    {
        print_r($post_tags);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get all selected tag in "publish_post" try below code. it will give you selected tag from post. remove `wp_die("all Tags");` after verify that you can get proper tags on publish post.

```
add_action( 'publish_post', 'post_published_notification', 10, 2 );
function post_published_notification( $ID, $post ) 
{
    $all_tags = $_POST['tax_input']['post_tag'];
    if ( $all_tags ) 
    {
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($all_tags);
        echo "</pre>";
        wp_die("all Tags");
    }
}
```

It will output all selected tags by comma separated like :

```
new10,new4,new5,new6,new7,new8,new9
```

Let me know if this works for you!

Comment: There is nothing in $_POST

Comment: i have tested code and it is working fine for me https://prnt.sc/pje76a. did you try with new post ?

Comment: Oh.. I'm checking this on draft posts from start.

Comment: it will also work with draft to publish post. did you try with changing post status from publish to draft  then publish post? did you get data in $_POST ?